# How to restrict data length in sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite

Can I restrict the data length for a column value in sqlite3?

ex: varchar name(5), Insert statement accepts more than 5 characters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SQLite treats `varchar(5)` as `text` (i.e. unlimited string) but you can add a [CHECK constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) to the column:

```
create table pancakes (
    name text check(name is null or length(name) <= 5)
)
```

This will give you a "constraint failed" error if your `name` is too long:

```
sqlite> create table pancakes (name text not null check(length(name) <= 5));
sqlite> insert into pancakes (name) values ('1234');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (name) values ('12345');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (name) values ('123456');
Error: constraint failed
```